# How to create a numeric triangle with user input in python?

Tags: python, numeric

I have to answer this question: Write a Python function triangle(n) that takes an integer argument n and print a numeric triangle of n layers as shown in the following examples. Test your answer the arguments: 1, 2, 5, 9 and 14.

```
 triangle(7)
 1
 12
 123
 1234
 12345
 123456
 1234567

 triangle(14)
 1
 12
 123
 1234
 12345
 123456
 1234567
 12345678
 123456789
 1234567890
 12345678901
 123456789012
 1234567890123
 12345678901234
```

I can't figure out how to do it other than using a list.

```
def triangle(n):
    line = [1]
    count = 2
    print(line)
    for i in range(1,n):
        line.append(count)
        count += 1
        print(line)
        if len(line) == 9:
            line.append(0)
            print(line)
            count = 1
triangle(5)
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But a list prints it like this. And i'm having a hard time with the 0 and getting it to start over counting back to 123,etc.

Comment: There are numerous solutions to this, including using a list. How about just doing `u''.join(line)` to finish it out with your list?

Comment: I'm still not understanding... How would I get the numbers If I used a string and where do I use `u' '.join(line)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt

```
def triangle(n):    
    s = ""
    for i in xrange(0,n):
        s +=  "{}".format((i+1)%10)
        print s
triangle(15)
```

outputs:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
12345678901
123456789012
1234567890123
12345678901234
123456789012345
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, probably the simplest:

1. print the digits one by one and use `print <value>,` (note the comma) to avoid a line break after each `print`. At the end, a `print` without parameters will produce just a line break.

   This way, you don't even have to build up a sequence.

   For when `print` is a function, the syntax is `print(<value>,end='')` and `print('')`, correspondingly.
2. To cycle the digits, use the modulo operation ([`%`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations))

Comment: Where would I use `print <value>,`? would I do `print(line,)`?

Comment: You didn't specify your Python version so I gave the syntax for both Python 2 (`print` is a statement by default) and 3 (`print` is a function).

Comment: I'm using Python 3. And how would I use the modulus operation to cycle through the digits? By saying, `for I in range(1,n): i % n`?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, the right word for `%` is [*modulo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (=remainder after division), not *modulus*.

Comment: Since you need to go up to `9` and then start over from `0`, the remainder after division by what number are you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

While there can be more elegant code:

```
def tri(n):
    start = 1
    while (n >= start):
        foo = ""
        for i in range(1, start+1):
            foo += str(i%10)
        print foo
        start += 1
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". This is obviously an exercise, just giving an answer won't teach him anything.

Comment: This is not the cleanest solution, either.

Comment: did i say this was the cleanest?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev StackOverflow is about discrete answers to specific questions. This is not CodeAcademy. If you really want to teach someone, start a chat with them.

Comment: I tried this code and it printed out the triangle, but the numbers kept increasing. It doesn't stop at 0 and repeat back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Almost a one-liner:

```
>>> import string
>>> def number_triangle(n):
...   print u''.join(string.digits[(i+1) % 10] for i in range(n))
... 
>>> for i in range(15):
...   number_triangle(i)
... 

1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
12345678901
123456789012
1234567890123
12345678901234
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I think it all has to be under one function.

Comment: Yes I noticed upon re-reading that the function is supposed to do the loop but it's so easy to combine all the pieces I left it "as an exercise" if you will.